# NUnit 3.0 ExpectedResult is always null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Migrating tests from NUnit 2.x to 3.x I replaced Result attribute with ExpectedResult for every TestCase. Anyway seems that ExpectedResult does not get the value passed.

My Code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class HashToolsTest
{
        [TestCase("Cantami o diva del pelide Achille l'ira funesta", ExpectedResult = "b4dd7f0b0ca6c25dd46cc096e45158eb")]
         public object MD5_Should_Hash_a_string_according_to_MD5_standards(string toHash) {
              string res = HashTools.MD5(toHash);
              return res;
         }
 }
```

and when i run the tests message is:

```
Expected: null
But was:  "b4dd7f0b0ca6c25dd46cc096e45158eb"

at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(TActual actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args) 
at  NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with Resharper 8.2 test runner window. (current beta version of resharper-nunit-Adapter do not fix the problem)

- Installed NUnit 3 Adapter trough VisualStudio Extensions
- Runned tests from test explorer window

Works

Comment: You need to upgrade Resharper to 10 version. It supports nUnit 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct NUnit Adapter or Test Runner for NUnit 3.0.

I'm using NUnit 3.0.1 and NUnit 3.0 Test Adapter and your example is working fine for me.

Comment: Using this packages .

        <packages><package id="NUnit" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
       <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.0.8-ctp-8" targetFramework="net45" />
        </packages>
...still doesn't work.
I'm using Vs 2012 Update 5 with 4.5 framework

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10945862)

Comment: @agold - Thanks alot for the advice, but as you can see on my reputation i wasn't able to comment on the original question. And as it seems, my advice pointed the OP to the right direction.